# Grails conditional html

Tags: grails

I was wondering how I can make this code in my view conditional - output it if there is a comment, but if there isn't a comment, don't output the empty `<p class="comment"></p>`

```
<p class="comment">
  ${progressItem.comment}
</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<g:if test="${(progressItem?.comment?.size() > 0)}">
  <p class="comment">
    ${progressItem.comment}
  </p>
</g:if>
```

Comment: Comments didn't display at all. Sorry I didn't include that